# Cannot install TQRChart to Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe7

When I install `TQrChart` to Delphi XE7, I finished all steps according to the guide of TeeChart’s  (in "QuickReport" subfolder). But XE7 reports this error:

> Cannot load package 'DclTee921.bpl' it contains unit
>   'VCLTee.TeeChartExp', which is also contained in package
>   'DclTeePro921'.

I've tried to install it three times, but I can not resolve this error.

The quickrep version is qr506 for XE7, just for win32 platform. The dcp is QR506RunDXE7.dcp, not quickrpt.dcp.

Comment: It sounds like you need to uninstall another version of it first.

Comment: Are you installing TeeChart pro version over default TeeChart that comes with Delphi. If so you might need to remove the default TeeChart components before installing the Pro Version. The reason why I'm talking about Pro version is becouse default version of TeeChart that comes with Delphi does not contain DclTeePro921 package which your error mentiones.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your TQRChart dpks making sure they reference the TeeChart packages you have installed in the IDE, rebuild and install them.
See the QuickReport article [here](http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/QuickReport.htm).